# I want Href to take me to a part of another webpage

Tags: html, css, button, href

[image: This is how the page is shown when the button is clicked in the other 2 pages[![And how it should be]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdt2r.png)I have a website with 3 pages and in each of one them is a button which should take me to a bottom part of the main page.

index.html is the main page and #r is for it to take me to the bottom part. When i click the button on that page it works perfectly, but when i do it on one of the two other pages it redirects me to the main page and the part i wanted but without all the css classes. 
How can i fix this? `href="./index.html/#r"`

I have tried different approaches but none of them seems to work.

Comment: What does *"without all the css classes"* mean?

Comment: i mean without all the css, it's just html

Comment: Then we'd need to *see* this not working. Clearly for some reason you CSS file is not being linked...which sounds like a path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `href="./index.html/#r"`, (i.e. `#r`  is not a separate file and `index-html` is not a directory in the filepath), but the anchor is directly appended to the filename of the page, like `href="./index.html#r"`

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple as you just have to specify a name or id to that part of the main web page, and then you can link it with other web pages by just putting both values(name of the page along with that part of its body) in "href" attribute.

For example-

```
<a href="page.html#anchor">text</a>
```

here page.html is the name of webpage and #anchor is the name or id of that specified part

hoping it will help you!!
greetings,
Om Chaudhary